# Freeing an array within a struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc, free

for an assignment I have to write a circular queue (which I imagine most of you are familiar with). I made a structure and a function that initializes a queue struct using dynamic memory. Note that I also have an array **arr** within the struct to which I assign memory.

For some reason I can't seem to free my array from memory.

```
struct queue {
  element_t *arr;    // dynamic array containing data elements
  int current_size;   // Counts number of elements in the queue
  int front, rear;   // Remark for later: extra fields need to be added here to make it a thread-safe queue as needed for the assigment
};


queue_t* queue_create(){
  struct queue *queue = malloc(sizeof(struct queue));

  if(queue == 0){  //check if memory available
    printf("Out of memory\n");
    return NULL;
  }

  queue -> current_size = 0;
  queue -> front = -1;
  queue -> rear = -1;
  queue -> arr = malloc(QUEUE_SIZE*sizeof(element_t));
  return queue;
}
```

I'm trying to free the memory when I'm done with it using a function queue_free. The function takes in a double pointer to a queue (part of the assignment).

```
void queue_free(queue_t** queue){
  free(**queue -> arr);
  free(*queue);
}
```

When I call the last function I got an error message saying:

```
queue.c: In function ‘queue_free’:
queue.c:39:16: error: request for member ‘arr’ in something not a structure or union
   free(**queue -> arr);
                ^
```

I've already checked with valgrind for leaks. The queue gets freed correctly but for some reason I can't get the address of my array.

Thanks in advance

P.S. free(queue -> arr); free(*queue -> arr); and free(**queue -> arr); all fail and generate the same error message.

Comment: Have you tried `free((*queue)->arr)`?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? you are posting a compiler error and then you talk about valgrind? How, if you haven't got an executable? Btw. if should be `free( (*queue)->arr );`

Comment: Actually, I was thinking you were a dereference short:  free(*(**queue)->arr);

Comment: I just tried free((*queue)->arr) now and it works. Thanks!
I still fail to understand why though.

Comment: because `*queue->arr` is equal to `*(queue->arr)`. So if `queue` is `queue_t **` you can't use `->` on it but have do dereference it first; that's done by the bracketing

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The free statement should look like `free((*queue)->arr)`.

Explanation: `queue_free` defines the `queue` variable as a pointer to a pointer to the `queue_t` struct. Now, in order to get to the pointer to the struct you need to remove one level of indirection using `(*queue)`; then you can use the dereference operator `->` to access `arr` member.

Now, the reason why the other options didn't work for you are:

- `free(queue -> arr)` - a pointer to a pointer of a queue_t structure does not have an `arr` member
- `free(*queue -> arr)` - the dereference operator (`'*'`) refers to the whole expression, i.e. `queue->arr`, which takes you back to the previous error
- `free(**queue -> arr)` - same as above